# Laravel 5.1 File Upload isValid() on string?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

So I am making a function for file uploading in my project.

however, when I try it I get this error : `Call to a member function isValid() on string`

My code for the upload function :

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $file = array('profielfoto' => $request->input('profielfoto'));

    $rules = array('profielfoto' => 'required',);

    $validator = Validator::make($file,$rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/profiel')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else{
        if($request->input('profielfoto')->isValid()){ //<- gives error
            $destinationPath = 'assets/uploads';
            $extension = $request->input('profielfoto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = rand(1111,9999).'.'.$extension;

            $request->input('profielfoto')->move($destinationPath,$fileName);



            Session::flash('alert-success', 'Foto uploaden gelukt');
            return redirect('/profiel');
        }
        else{
            Session::flash('alert-danger', 'Foto uploaden mislukt');
            return redirect('/profiel');
        }
    }
}
```

The form in the blade view on the 4th line from down below is the location for the input!

```
<form method="POST" action="/profiel/upload" files="true">
                      {!! csrf_field() !!}
                      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                      <input type="hidden" class="form-control id2" id="id2"  name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                        <img src="assets/images/avatar.png" alt="gfxuser" class="img-circle center-block">
                        <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <label class="center-block text-center" for="fotoinput">Kies uw foto</label>
              <input class="center-block" type="file"  name="profielfoto" id="profielfoto">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Verander foto</button>
                      </form>
```

Comment: Try `if($request->file('profielfoto')->isValid()){`

Comment: @Matt now the `$request->file('profielfoto'); returns null`.. so validator fails..

Comment: Could you please show me the view where there is the file input with profielfoto on it?

Comment: But if you reach that code, doesn't it means it passed the validation?

Comment: @Matt i posted the code in the OP :)

Comment: @Amarnasan You can see in my code that I check if the validator fails before checking if the file isValid() but when i have $request->file('profielfoto') it returns null in dd($request->file('profielfoto') and if i use $request->input i can't check isValid() because it's seen as a string.

Comment: try use $request->has('profielfoto') instead of $request->input('profielfoto')->isValid()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must ask `isValid()` to a file, not to the name of the file. That's why you get the error. You can get the file through `$request->file()` or through  `Input::file()` :

```
else{
    if( $request->file('profielfoto')->isValid()){ //<- gives error
```

Also your form should include the correct enctype to send files:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I use a Request instead of Input. And sorry but this isn't an answer in anyway..?

Comment: It is an answer: You must ask "isValid" to a file, not to the name of the file. And you can get the file two ways: Through request or through the alias of the request.

Comment: `array:1 [▼
  "profielfoto" => null
]` 
When i use `$request->file(''profielfoto);`

Comment: Ok, so you didn't get a file called "profielfoto". Then you'll get your "Foto uploaden mislukt" . Isn't it?

Comment: I got my own error flashdata so it gave me the Validator failed. Because I got my $validator->fails() function above the isValid check. and as the $request->file returns null and $request->input returns the file name w/ extension. but can't call isValid on as it's seen as a string. I don't know what else i can use

Comment: Damn, you forgot to set your <form> to the correct enctype!

Comment: oh wow i never used that before.. is it something laravel related? Thanks btw !! you get some points!

Comment: @StefanoGroenland Glad to help! The `enctype` (encoding type) is not related to laravel, but to html.

Comment: Ah okay thanks anyways! now onto defining specific extensions only ! a new challenge =P

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use as this.

```
$file = $request -> file('Filedata');
if (!$file -> isValid()) {
     echo Protocol::ajaxModel('JSEND_ERROR', 'not an valid file.');
     return;
}
```

Add attribute on

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: just modify 'Filedata' in my code to 'profielfoto' .